# Handling invalid input in input stream operator >>

Tags: c++, istream

What is the recommended (standard) way of handling invalid input in extraction operator:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SomeType& val) {
    // ...
    return is;
}
```

Should it set `std::ios_base::failbit` and return immediately? Is it okay to leave the `val` object in undefined state, with possibly some of it's variables already changed?

Comment: These are the standard rules https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction. Since c++11 the numerical input functions set their output to `0` on failure https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Answer (score 1):

According to [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) documentation the recommended layout:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SomeType& val) {
    std::istream::sentry s(is);
    if (s) {
         // do parse
         if (parsing_failed) {
             // optionally, to make it work like built-in operators:
             // val = {};
             is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
         }
    }
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the convention of the standard library - that is, set `failbit`, leave the stream pointing to the same place you started with and set your input to some default value - the standard library sets inputs to `0` on error, so do whatever the logical equivalent of that for your type is, probably `val = SomeType{};`.

Comment: I don't think that it's recommended to "leave the stream pointing to the same place you started with". What if the object being read is large and parsing fails at the very end? That would require rewinding all the data. If the stream is in `failed` state there shouldn't be any following read operations.

Comment: That's the behaviour the STL uses. Deviate from it if you want, but understand that it might lead to surprising behaviour.

Comment: Actually that's not true for `bool` and `std::boolalpha` mode. If you try parsing `"truth"` it will leave the stream at position 3 (at least latest gcc).

Comment: Additionally if you think about parsing large structures, megabytes of input, rewinding all of it would result in huge cost... I think it would go against C++ philosophy of not paying for what you don't use.